# How to speed up multiple http requsts in Python

Tags: python

I want to fetch whois data from a txt file with 50000 urls. It's working but takes at least 20 minutes. What can i do to improve performance of this

```
import whois
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading
import time

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2500)

def query(domain):
    while True:
        try:
            w = whois.whois(domain)
            fwrite = open("whoISSuccess.txt", "a")
            fwrite.write('\n{0} : {1}'.format(w.domain, w.expiration_date))
            fwrite.close()
        except:
            time.sleep(3)
            continue
        else:
            break


with open('urls.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines = line.rstrip("\n\r")
        pool.submit(query, lines)


pool.shutdown(wait=True)
```

Comment: Probably you can eliminate some delay by batching the write process. Have you looked at your filesystem io utilization?

Comment: On a side-note: I wouldn't write to a single file from multiple threads this naively (unless you want a corrupted file)
. Collect the results and write the file later in the main thread. This is not the bottle-neck anyway.

Comment: It’s not impacting performance, my network is. I can’t even browse when the script is running

Comment: @tehhowch I'd put my money that the bottle-neck is the `whois.whois` call and not writing to the file, but without profiling output we can only guess

Comment: Have you compared the performance with the `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`? That uses the `multiprocessing` module and may be faster.

Comment: You are hitting the whois server with 2500 parallel request from the same IP address. They probably have some rate-limiting and/or throttling in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things to improve the speed:

1. Use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process), rather than `threading` as python Threads do not really run in parallel, while processes will be managed the OS and truly run in parallel.
2. Secondly, have each process write to its own file, e.g. `<url>.txt`, as having all processes write to the same file will cause lock contention on the file writing, which significantly slows your program. After all processes have completed you can then aggregate all files to a single one if this is a critical requirement. Alternatively, you can just keep the whois result in memory and then write it out to a file in the end.

Comment: It will be much faster to collect the results and write a single file later in the main thread rather than creating 50000  (according to OP) files, partly due to context switching the CPU would have to do in order to write 50000 files  in "parallel"

Comment: That is true as well.

Comment: thanks for answer but i crashed my computer:) could you please give me an example loop for my code. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to limit the number of processes currently running. I would start small and increase it gradually.

Comment: @gkivanov i've used os.cpu_count but it either stuck at single cpu or crash my computer so i couldn't figure it out how to use loop since my def is taking a single url at a time